# Weblogic javax.naming.NameNotFoundException while running application

Tags: jdbc, weblogic, jndi, weblogic11g

I have created a data source name in `Weblogic 10.3.6` as `jdbc/appsmDS` and the same name has been given in application to lookup.

However when I am trying to run application, I am getting the following error

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc/appsmDS' 
didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/appsmDS'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: can you try looking up java:jdbc/appsmDS

Comment: @Satya with `java:jdbc/appsmDS` I was able to run application, so it has to be `java:jdbc/appsmDS`?

Comment: yes , when looking up the full JNDI structure maps to java:jdbc/appsmsDS. Posting all of it as answer kindly accept

Comment: @Satya Kindly post as an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Comment: Plese see my answer also http://stackoverflow.com/a/36981908/3506427 . My problem was that the local sql server service was stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when looking up the DS  the full JNDI structure maps to `java:jdbc/appsmsDS`.

Please use it for lookup.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in this case is probably that the datasource is not deployed in the "server" inside weblogic domain.

Comment: I'm sorry but that link doesn't seem to point to the right post.

Answer (score 2):

This exception happens when the property `provider.url` is pointing at the AdminServer (localhost:7001, in my case) and JDBC is not installed.

You may have other instances where it is installed, check your JNDI TREE to verify this.

Greetings,
JFM

Answer (score 1):

`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:` This will generally occur if any of the xml files like `ejb-jar.xml` and `weblogic-ejbjar.xml` are missing in the ear file deployed. The only workaround is to generate a fresh ear file with all the xml files included.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have clicked on the "Activate Changes" button on the left top corner and also check your xxxxxxDataSource-nnnn-jdbc.xml file is created under config/jdbc directory.