# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'MyDB'. Resolved '' Weblogic 12.1.3. c

Tags: java, jndi, weblogic12c

While migrating from Tomcat to Weblogic 12.1.3 I got this exception `javax.naming.namenotfoundexception while trying to look up` 
then I have tried the following :
[NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc' only when publishing from Eclipse Kepler but not Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355945/namenotfoundexception-while-trying-to-lookup-jdbc-only-when-publishing-from-e)
and
[How to access JNDI data source defined in weblogic 10.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218663/how-to-access-jndi-data-source-defined-in-weblogic-10-3-6)

I got the in titled error now

My lookup code

```
ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("MyDB");
```

in weblogic **JNDI Name**

```
MyDB
```

Any help please?

Comment: Try prefix "java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB"

Comment: @Maas where in weblogic or the application?

Comment: In the calling client

Comment: @Maas i just did and i got  While trying to look up comp/env/jdbc/MyDB remaining name 'comp/env/jdbc/MyDB

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand your comment. Do you mean even after using "java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB" you got NameNotFound?

Comment: @Maas yes i got javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/MyDB

Comment: See if this thread helps: https://community.jboss.org/message/251298

Comment: @Maas the same i guess this version is buged

Comment: Hmmm, may be... lets wait for other experts to add their comments

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unlike Tomcat, weblogic creates multiple servers (Usually an Admin Server, plus at least one other). Each server has to be allocated the data source. In a clustered environment, you need to apply the datasource to the cluster servers.

1. Log into the Weblogic console, and check the datasource JNDI name (don't confuse this with the datasource name, which is purely to keep the console listing looking pretty). The JNDI name should be something like jdbc/MyDB
2. Check the datasource **Targets** tab, and make sure it is applied to the server/cluster you are going to deploy your web app to.
3. Restart Weblogic. I find that data sources sometimes need this before they become visible to application code.
4. Deploy your web app to the correct server/cluster.

You should be to connect to the datasource as normal. I always use a Spring JNDI bean, so I can't help with the exact syntax. The suggestions by @Maas look good.

Comment: I found AdminServer must be checked on Targets tab. That was not intuitive to me when I configured Weblogic.

Comment: Man we wasted hours on this here. The AdminServer indeed must be checked. Thanks CodeChops.

Comment: I had to check AdminServer and also update the JNDI name from myDB to jdbc/myDB. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting the server after deployment helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check the JNDI case (MyDB != MyDb). It sounds trivial, but it happened to me and had a hard time spotting it. Since this is the first thread google returns when searching for this issue, I post it here in case it helps.

Besides that, @kiwiron 's answer covers everything else.

Answer (score 0):

For me, starting the managed server from Windows command line instead of starting it using the WebLogic Admin console solved the `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` problem. Not sure why this was the case though.