# Specify JDBC connection details

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect to a JDBC data source (on virtual machine)

I am specifying the same in the following formats. In settings.xml as below;

```
<properties>
  <jdbc.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//remotevm.us.mycompany.com:1521/XE</jdbc.url> 
  <jdbc.username>my_local</jdbc.username> 
  <jdbc.password>my_local</jdbc.password>
</properties>
```

Also in my weblogic console (under Data sources), I specify the following URL;

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//remotevm.us.mycompany.com:1521:XE
```

Are there any issues with the above?

I am asking this as I am getting an error:

```
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'jdbc.APP'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'APP'
```

Just to add, I am able to connect through SQL developer with the above details (Hostname, Service name, Username/Pwd).

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258461/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-unable-to-resolve-mydb-resolved-weblog

Comment: ...and how do you initialize your datasource in your code?