# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:while trying to lookup

Tags: java, exception, jar, ejb, weblogic

I have a problem that I get the following error.
Project has jar about this services and my web.xml following

Please help me.

```
<ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/KpsSessionFacade</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>tr.com.meop.db.session.KpsSessionFacadeLocal</local>
    <ejb-link>KpsSessionFacade</ejb-link>
</ejb-local-ref>
```

Log:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up comp/env/ejb/KpsSessionFacade in /app/ejb/meop-service-1.jar#KisiManagerService.; remaining name 'comp/env/ejb/KpsSessionFacade'
>
> at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
>       at tr.com.meop.scheduler.client.MernisWsFactory.log(MernisWsFactory.java:686)
>       at tr.com.meop.scheduler.client.MernisWsFactory.tcKimliktenAdresSorgula(MernisWsFactory.java:300)
>       at tr.com.meop.business.kisi.service.KisiManagerServiceImpl.findKisiBilgisiByTckn(KisiManagerServiceImpl.java:344)
>       .
>       .
>       .
>
> at tr.com.meop.app.kisi.action.KisiAction.bulKisiBilgilerByTcknProcess(KisiAction.java:684)
>       at tr.com.meop.app.kisi.action.KisiAction.bulKisiBilgilerByTckn(KisiAction.java:672)
>       .
>       .

Comment: what is your lookup code ? @AhmetHakanBillur

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a prefix java in your lookup code. It will be like below:

```
"java:comp/env/ejb/KpsSessionFacade"
```

A full example is given in this link: [javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound](https://developer.jboss.org/message/251298)

Some steps are used for checking, is given here: [javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'MyDB'. Resolved '' Weblogic 12.1.3. c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25262410/2293534)

Comment: It was already that public static final String JNDI_FACADE_KPS = "java:comp/env/ejb/KpsSessionFacade";

Comment: Then please check second link. @AhmetHakanBillur