# How to use JNDI DataSource provided by WebLogic 12.2.1 in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jndi, weblogic12c

I created a JNDI connection with the following Values:

i selected `Generic Data Source` option

**Name**: jdbc/sampleDataSource

**JNDI Name**: jdbc/sampleDataSource

**Spring Config File:**

`<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/sampleDataSource" />`

I'm getting below error.

```
Error An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Error javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.sampleDataSource' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/sampleDataSource'
Error While trying to lookup 'jdbc.sampleDataSource' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/sampleDataSource'
```

I was unable to resolve it. 
How do i configure in Spring 4.
Any addition jar file is required. Please help on this.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440419/weblogic-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-while-running-application

Comment: @Baderous: I tried `<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jdbc/sampleDataSource" />` same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes this happens when you forget to `Target` your defined `datasource` to a specific server. You can find it in `Weblogic`'s administration server :

[image]

then in the `Targets` tab:

[image]

you should select the target.

If that wasn't the problem, you may try the way of getting your `datasource` in the `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/mcdsDS"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

And use the **dataSource** reference wherever you need a `datasource`.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: `<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/dimeDataSource" />`this also working fine when i select the server.

Comment: @Rajesh: Happy it helped!